# iterating over tuples inside a tuple and using string inside tuples as a variable

Tags: python, mysql, tuples, pymysql

I have many number of tables inside a database, I am using pymysql to connect to my db and got all table names. When I print all table names they are stored something like follows:

```
tables = (('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), etc...)
```

What I want to do is for each table, turn them into a dataframe with their own table name. This is what I've tried:

```
for table in tables:
   table[0] = pd.read_sql(f'select * from {table[0]}', con = conn)
```

and also by converting tuples into a list, however I think the string is the problem, how do I get rid of apostrophe so I can use them as a variable or is there no such way?

I couldn't find any relevant question on SO, only some stuff that gave me some ideas.

[TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment when swapping values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735838/typeerror-tuple-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-when-swapping-values)

[How can I iterate over only the first variable of a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061336/how-can-i-iterate-over-only-the-first-variable-of-a-tuple)

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are trying to do? Do you want a list (or a dictionary) of dataframes?

Comment: I'm just trying to assign dataframe into a variable with table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tuple are immutable object you cannot do this, the result returned by first query is a tuple of tuple:

```
some_tuple[dome_index] = value
```

this will generate a tuple of tuple with one element is the dataframe:

```
tables = tuple((pd.read_sql(f'select * from {table_name}', con = conn),) for (table_name,) in tables)
```

**EDITS:**

You could create a tuple of pairs `table_name, dataframe`:

```
tables = tuple((table_name, pd.read_sql(f'select * from {table_name}', con = conn)) for (table_name,) in tables)
```

You need dictionary:

```
tables = {table_name: pd.read_sql(f'select * from {table_name}', con = conn) for (table_name,) in tables}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for making it (df,) instead of (df)?

Comment: you could create pairs to keep the table name in the first index and the dataframe in the second index, check my edits

Comment: Thanks!!!! After that I can change them to dictionary therefore I can access dataframe with table name?

Comment: You need dictionary just use dictionary comprehensive directly check my edits